# Do node.js packages completely get deleted after I delete the project folder?

Tags: node.js, backend

I'm new to node.js and currently working on it. I'm doing several projects to improve myself and add different packages with npm to each one of them. When I'm done with the project, I delete the project folder. Does that also delete all the packages and dependencies of that project or not? If not, where does npm install them so I can delete every file for a project after I'm done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete the project folder every dependency or package you have installed will also be deleted. Every dependency/package you install is going to be stored in the **node_modules** folder, so when you delete the project folder you also delete the node_modules folder. Also a little tip, becauase this file is so big it is a good practice to ignore this folder when uploading on github.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? These modules are deleted with the folder but packages like nodemon don't get deleted? What are the differences?

Comment: Nodemon is also been deleted. Pretty much everything you install with "npm install package-name" is been deleted when you delete the node_modules folder (or the project folder)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are deleted

Node modules are installed in `node_modules` directory in each project